# Parametizing parabolic nurbs surface

Tags: mathematics, nurbs-surface

[image]
*Wireframe of nurbs selected, default z-surface parabola underneath*

[How to model an accurate parabolic mirror with a known focal point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129126/how-to-model-an-accurate-parabolic-mirror-with-a-known-focal-point)

[Animating z surface math functions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/animating-z-surface-math-functions)

Reminded me of an afterthought of instead  using a [NURBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#NURBS) surface, which albeit my maths is rusting fast, the default nurbs surface is parabolic, or a very close approximation to.  Image above shows transforms of default NURB surface as to overlay the parabola created by add z-surface default.

How to calculate (*Or theory behind*) values of the 4 x 4 grid of [knots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/create-nurbs-surface-with-python) required to add a NURBS approximation of focus 1 parabola $$(y^2 + x^2) / 4$$